# How to effectively link isolated apps of the same product?

Tags: interaction-design, accessibility, ux-field, human-interface-guideline, product-design

Our product has many categories of features (e.g. Create/Manage sports activities, Book a play field, Book a Coach, Entertainment related events etc).

However, we plan to divide these features into individual apps so that it serves only for specific users to make sure best experience and make it less clumsy.

But our major concern is

### "How to link all these apps in one place that users can reach all apps"?

Answer (score 2):

you can do what Adobe did with creative cloud, they created an area where you can manage, update and open all of your apps as well as download and install new ones, all are from the same suite, and they all have a description.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is interesting. In fact, I have arrived at a similar solution that pops up with a flash window when the user opens the app saying "we have isolated the apps from xyz product" suggesting to link showing like above image you shared, once they linked they can launch the app from the menu bar. the same menu bar will be mirrored in all isolated apps. Thanks for quick response and it was thoughtful.